# Laravel DB transaction and events

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I want that If any of the products is updated we fire an event once after the transaction finish

```php
DB::transaction(function() {
   foreach($products as $product) {
       $product = Product::find($product->id) ;
       $product->price = 2;
       $product->update();
   } 
});
```

Comment: you can use isDirty method before update product to check if product has property change https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#examining-attribute-changes

Comment: You can fire event under the line `$product->update()`. What's the big deal?

Comment: @AbdullahShakir the only deal with the approach you mentioned is that the event will be fired before the transaction will be committed, which in some cases might lead to interesting scenarios: what if the transaction failed due to some errors or the event will get processed for an object that is not yet saved in database

Comment: I got it. @PrideMutumbami wants to trigger the event after the transaction is commited?

Answer (score 3):

Laravel Eloquent models allowing you to hook into the following moments

`retrieved`, `creating`, `created`, `updating`, `updated`, `saving`, `saved`, `deleting`, `deleted`, `restoring`, `restored`, and `replicating`

The above events are varies based on the laravel version.

**Laravel 8.x**

If you are using Laravel 8.x, then Laravel took care of eloquent events with the transaction.

You just need to use `public $afterCommit = true;` in your observer.
Then the eloquent event will fire after committing a transaction.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers-and-database-transactions

**Laravel  <  8.x**

Those who are using the below version, Please have a look at the below code.

You need to create a trait inside `app/Traits` folder

In  `app/Traits/TransactionalEloquentEvents.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionCommitted;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

    trait TransactionalEloquentEvents
    {
        protected static $eloquentEvents = ['created', 'updated'];
    
        protected static $queuedTransactionalEvents = [];
    
        public static function bootTransactionalEloquentEvents()
        {
            $dispatcher = static::getEventDispatcher();
            if (!$dispatcher) {
                return;
            }
    
            foreach (self::$eloquentEvents as $event) {
                static::registerModelEvent($event, function (Model $model) use ($event) {
                    /*get updated parameters*/
                    $updatedParams = array_diff($model->getOriginal(),$model->getAttributes());
                    if ($model->getConnection()->transactionLevel()) {
                        self::$queuedTransactionalEvents[$event][] = $model;
                    } else {
                        Log::info('Event fired without transaction '.$event. json_encode($updatedParams));
                        /* Do your operation here*/
                    }
                });
            }
    
            $dispatcher->listen(TransactionCommitted::class, function (TransactionCommitted $event) {
                if ($event->connection->transactionLevel() > 0) {
                    return;
                }
                foreach ((self::$queuedTransactionalEvents ?? []) as $eventName => $models) {
                    foreach ($models as $model) {
                        Log::info('Event fired with transaction '.$eventName);
                        /* Do your operation here*/
                    }
                }
                self::$queuedTransactionalEvents = [];
            });
        }
    }
```

In your model `app/Models/Product.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Traits\TransactionalEloquentEvents;

class Product extends Model
{
    use TransactionalEloquentEvents;

}
```

Note: In case of `updated` eloquent event. You will get the updated parameters through the `$updatedParams` variable.

The above case handles both transaction and non-transaction model operations.

I am maintaining a log here for each activity. You can do your operation too.

Comment: Does the `public $afterCommit = true;` also delay the `-ing` events until after the transaction? I don't see anything to indicate that the `$afterCommit` only handles the `-ed` events, but I can't quite wrap my head around a `-ing` event firing after the transaction has been committed.

Comment: -ing event is a pre-hook and -ed is post-hook

Comment: yes, but does an -ing event get fired during a database transaction if the $afterCommit flag is true in the observer? Otherwise, the record would actually exist in the database (after transaction) before the -ing event fired.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#observers-and-database-transactions

Comment: When models are being created within a database transaction, you may want to instruct an observer to only execute its event handlers after the database transaction is committed. You may accomplish this by defining an $afterCommit property on the observer. If a database transaction is not in progress, the event handlers will execute immediately:

Comment: In short yes but after the TransactionCommitted event

Answer (score -1):

I have just checked the Laravel source code. I think you can utilize the `Illuminate\Database\Events\TransactionCommitted` event, which is provided out of the box. You can simply register this event with a listener in the `EventServiceProvider`:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        TransactionCommitted::class => [
            WhatYouWantToDo::class,
        ],
    ];
}
```